# How to get a custom text for bibliography references?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

Currently I have a list like

```
[1] Some Author. Some Book. Viley, 2010. 122 pages.
[2] Other Author. Other Book. Springer, 2020. 211 pages.
[3] Lorem Ipsum. Dolor sit amet. Consectetur, MDCLXIV. Much pages.
....
```

When I \cite, I'm getting [1], [2] and so on.

But I want to get references like the following

```
You can read some more in the books [Some Author, 2010] and [Other Author, 2020].
But the most extremely astonishing conclusions can be found at [That good old book].
```

and the list like

```
[Some Author, 2010] Some Author. Some Book. Viley, 2010. 122 pages.
[Other Author, 2020] Other Author. Other Book. Springer, 2020. 211 pages.
[That good old book] Lorem Ipsum. Dolor sit amet. Consectetur, MDCLXIV. Much pages.
....
```

Is there any way/s/ to get it?

And sure, I need all the links from a \cite to a corresponding entry within the list to work well.

Comment: Can you add a short test document? Maybe the shorthands from biblatex might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Use `apalike` style instead of `abbrv`.

Example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

This is an example of a paragraph with in-text
citations using the apalike BibTeX style.
Here is a reference to a journal article with
a single author \cite{article1}, to a journal
article with two authors \cite{article2} and
three authors \cite{article3}, and to a book
with four authors \cite{book4}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{sampleBibFile}
\end{document}
```

[image]